# Amazon DynamoDB table w/ Elastic Beanstalk not setting up correct parameters

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I have an example `Dynamodb` project from Amazon that when uploaded to an instance of `Elastic Beanstalk` environment, generates a `Dynamodb` table. Howevever, after generating the table is missing a few parameters.

Here is the code to the `Elastic Beanstalk` instance:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2010-2013 Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License").
 * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * A copy of the License is located at
 * 
 *  http://aws.amazon.com/apache2.0
 * 
 * or in the "license" file accompanying this file. This file is distributed
 * on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either
 * express or implied. See the License for the specific language governing
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */

package com.amazonaws.geo.util;

import com.amazonaws.geo.GeoDataManagerConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeDefinition;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.CreateTableRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeySchemaElement;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.KeyType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.LocalSecondaryIndex;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.Projection;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProjectionType;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughput;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ScalarAttributeType;

/**
 * Utility class.
 * */
public class GeoTableUtil {

    /**
     * <p>
     * Construct a create table request object based on GeoDataManagerConfiguration. The users can update any aspect of
     * the request and call it.
     * </p>
     * Example:
     * 
     * <pre>
     * AmazonDynamoDBClient ddb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());
     * Region usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2);
     * ddb.setRegion(usWest2);
     * 
     * CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = GeoTableUtil.getCreateTableRequest(config);
     * CreateTableResult createTableResult = ddb.createTable(createTableRequest);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * @return Generated create table request.
     */
    public static CreateTableRequest getCreateTableRequest(GeoDataManagerConfiguration config) {
        CreateTableRequest createTableRequest = new CreateTableRequest()
                .withTableName(config.getTableName())
                .withProvisionedThroughput(
                        new ProvisionedThroughput().withReadCapacityUnits(10L).withWriteCapacityUnits(5L))
                .withKeySchema(
                        new KeySchemaElement().withKeyType(KeyType.HASH).withAttributeName(
                                config.getHashKeyAttributeName()),
                        new KeySchemaElement().withKeyType(KeyType.RANGE).withAttributeName(
                                config.getRangeKeyAttributeName()))
                .withAttributeDefinitions(
                        new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.N).withAttributeName(
                                config.getHashKeyAttributeName()),
                        new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S).withAttributeName(
                                config.getRangeKeyAttributeName()),
                        new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.N).withAttributeName(
                                config.getGeohashAttributeName()),
                        new AttributeDefinition().withAttributeType(ScalarAttributeType.S).withAttributeName(
                                config.getBuruMsgAttributeName()))
                .withLocalSecondaryIndexes(
                        new LocalSecondaryIndex()
                                .withIndexName(config.getGeohashIndexName())
                                .withKeySchema(
                                        new KeySchemaElement().withKeyType(KeyType.HASH).withAttributeName(
                                                config.getHashKeyAttributeName()),
                                        new KeySchemaElement().withKeyType(KeyType.RANGE).withAttributeName(
                                                config.getGeohashAttributeName()))
                                .withProjection(new Projection().withProjectionType(ProjectionType.ALL)));

        return createTableRequest;
    }
}
```

Which should create a table with these parameters:
`HashKey`
`RangeKey`
`Geohash`
`BuruMsg`

and range/hash indices of:
`Geohash`
and `HashKey`

However my table only constructs with `Hash`, `Range` and `geohash`. It never adds my `BuruMsg` attribute.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Here is a picture of me attempting to insert an item into the database on AWS Console.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema of DynamoDB tables only specifies the hash key, optional range key, and optional index keys.  The schema does not cover attribute fields that are uninvolved in a key or index. I believe that is why your `BuruMsg` field does not appear in the management console UI.  You can certainly put data to that field, and you will observe it in the item listing in the management console.

But defining attributes is helpful to client software, such as the Java and .NET ORM libraries.  There may be nothing wrong with your code.